# Send html file as email body content using android intent

Tags: android, html, file, email, android-intent

I have an ecommerce app that shares the product as html document. Using this code I can send the product.html as attachment. I want to send the html document as the body of email instead of attachment.

Here is my code :

```
private void sendEmail(Context context, String emailTo, String emailCC,
                       String subject, String emailText, List<String> filePaths) {

    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    emailIntent.setType(TEXT_HTML);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emailTo});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{emailCC});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

    ArrayList<Uri> fileUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    for (String file : filePaths) {
        File fileIn = new File(file);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
        fileUris.add(uri);
    }

    emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUris);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, context.getString(R.string.send_by_email))); }
```

Comment: can you plz share your html document look like..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that needs to go into the body can be set into your intent this way e.g. puts your builds version name as the body of the email. You can replace that with your html content. Have never tried that personally, You might need some conversion.

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
```

Comment: it is only displaying the path of the file, is there any way to put the whole 
 html file as email body?

Comment: I am assuming you are doing this.  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, fileUris); If you do that You will get what you are seeing. You would need to get the contents of the file in text format and add that instead.

Comment: hey this worked but I am getting the whole HTML code as body, what I want is the content. I mean the rendered HTML file. Can you please help me further?

Comment: Can you accept this answer if it worked and ask another one?